# Primitive Axon App run as Fat JAR Doesn't Autoconfigure Axon Beans

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, axon, fatjar

PROBLEM:

RESEARCH: At https://gitlab.com/ZonZonZon/simple-axon.git I've made up a simple **Axon-app** to show that **JAR-artifact** built with **Gradle-plugin** `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow` doesn't autoconfigure Axon beans when (when run as JAR). Though it runs fine under Intellij.

From project root in terminal:

```
run gradle clean build shadowJar;
java -jar build/simpleaxon.jar;
```

Stacktrace is enclosed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/axonframework/np2mJvEUkb0/oM-pyHFiAQAJ). I expect that Axon Autocongiguration provides beans like CommandBus, Snapshotter and other by default.

QUESTION: How to autoconfigure default axon beans in a fat jar?

Comment: See here https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/335

Comment: Doesn't help. `123` is my favourite input choice, by the way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, this took my some investigation to get a hunch what is going wrong, but I know what the problem is.
Quick notice, it's not an Axon specific thing, rather the plugin you are using.

I ran your sample project and indeed ended up with the same result; no Axon beans were being wired, ever. That led me to investigate the process of creating fat JAR's step by step. First Maven, then Spring Boot with Maven, then Gradle with Spring Boot and finally with the Shadow plugin you are referring too.

This endeavour landed me on [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1828)) issue, which states as much as "projects which require the use of META-INF files need to add *this* to the shadow plugin, and this should be documented".

The portion referenced through *this* is the following:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.PropertiesFileTransformer

// Left out all other specifics from your 'build.gradle' file

shadowJar {
    // Required for Spring
    mergeServiceFiles()
    append 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
    append 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
    append 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
    transform(PropertiesFileTransformer) {
        paths = ['META-INF/spring.factories' ]
        mergeStrategy = "append"
    }

    setArchiveFileName("simpleaxon.jar")
    getDestinationDirectory().set(new File(projectDir, "./build"))
}
```

After adding that piece of logic to *your* `build.gradle` file, I could run your sample project as expected.

Comment: Tested as JAR and in Docker container. Works perfectly. Thanks a lot for quick assistance from Axon team.

Comment: That's great news @Zon :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've hit a similar issue when using Axon in a multimodule Gradle project. The app would not work when packaged and worked fine in IDE. The exact error I was getting was

```
org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.UnsupportedHandlerException: Unable to resolve parameter 0 in handler
```

The reason for this was because `ParameterResolverFactories` were not loaded due to the `META-INF/services` resources not being resolved correctly in the `shadow jar` plugin as @Steven hinted.

I've managed to fix it with simply (using Kotlin DSL in Gradle):

```
tasks.shadowJar {
  mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it wasn't enough, only the extensive solution from @Steven did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Steven 's solution was the only one working for me, after searching for a long time for other solutions.

The Gradle Kotlin Version looks like this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1828#issuecomment-607352468:

```kts
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.PropertiesFileTransformer
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
}
...
tasks.shadowJar {
    // Required for Spring.
    // The shadowJar plugin should merge the services correctly, but it doesn't!
    mergeServiceFiles()
    append("META-INF/spring.handlers")
    append("META-INF/spring.schemas")
    append("META-INF/spring.tooling")
    transform(
        PropertiesFileTransformer().apply {
            paths = mutableListOf("META-INF/spring.factories")
            mergeStrategy = "append"
        })
}
```